# GKE cluster autoscaler vs Autoscaling in Managed instance groups

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I am using Google Container Engine . Now I want auto scaling functionality in my cluster . As per documentation **GKE autoscaler** is in **beta release** . I can also enable autoscaling in **instance group** that is managing cluster nodes . 
Cluster autoscaler add/remove nodes so that all scheduled pods have a place to run where instance group add/remove nodes based on  different policies like average cpu utilization .
I think by adjusting pods CPU limit and target CPU utilization for pods in Kubernetes autoscaler , Managed Instance Group autoscaling can also be used to resize GKE cluster .
So my question is what should I use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer - don't use GCE MIG autoscaling feature. It will just not work properly with your cluster.

See details in this FAQ:
https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#should-i-use-a-cpu-usage-based-node-autoscaler-with-kubernetes

(read the question  linked above and 2 next ones)

Answer (score 0):

As per GCP docs :

"Caution: Do not enable Compute Engine autoscaling for managed instance groups for your cluster nodes. GKE's cluster autoscaler is separate from Compute Engine autoscaling. This can lead to node pools failing to scale up or scale down as the Compute Engine autoscaler will be in conflict with GKE's cluster autoscaler"

More Details :

- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler